# Isekai manga/manhwa involving a daughter manager game

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I think its a manwha but I could be misremembering it, and I know it's an isekai.
Its starts with the mc playing a daughter manager game in an Internet cafe  and I'm pretty sure is a magical setting. Similar vibes to *The Archmage's Daughter*.
And I might be confusing this with another one but I'm pretty sure she starts off with a different hair colour and then her 'father' changes it to match his via a magical earring.

And that's all I can remember. If anyone can help it would be appreciated, I've been trying to find it for months.

Comment: You mean a game like Princess Maker?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Carpe Diem](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/carpe-diem-sae-un)*.

> My god, is it easy to live! While I was doing a night shift at a PC room, I decided to **play a daughter raising game** out of pure boredom and nostalgia. But the ending she wound up with was... an Old merchant's concubine. When she got too annoyed and tried to find a different game to play next, a pop-up screen came up on her computer. [You are invited to our world! A place where you can get anything you want!] As soon as she clicked the yes button, she heard a butler's voice:"It's time to wake up, My Lady." Before she knew it, **she had become the "daughter" of the game she just played**! Ah, she probably would've chosen a better name if she'd known this. Rollypolly Perero. Why did a pack of cookies have to be in front of her when she typed in the name? Could a 24 year-old trapped in a 10 year-old's body successfully manage to become an adult?

The synopsis matches the question; the MC is working at an internet cafe and passes time playing a daughter raising sim, much like Princess Maker. She keeps getting endings she doesn't like, and goes to a different game, but as she enters the starting data, she finds herself in the game as the ten year old child she just created.

Her father is described as one of the top-four mages. After an incident, he gives her a set of magical earrings that changes her hair color from the initial silver to a dark blue, matching her father.

[image: Original appearance] [image: New appearance, with father and butler]