# Manga/Manhwa/Manhua where the female lead is transported or transmigrated into to the body of a girl with white hair but changes it to blue

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The female lead is transported/transmigrated into the body of girl who is the daughter of a magician. I think before the female lead took over the body the girl and her father didn't have a good relationship. Apparently the girl didn't like her father or something like that.

Also the girl got sick and died before the female lead took over. She was still a kid when this happened. The girl had white but when the female lead took over her body she changed her hair to blue (the same color as her father's).

She had a system- or status screen thing that she used. Also the female lead has memory of her past life.

I don't remember when I last read this. The manga was in full color.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was full color

Comment: About when did you read this? About how many chapters were there, or how many did you read? Do you remember anything that happens after the girl reincarnates? I'm guessing this is a shoujo romance manga; do you remember anything about the male lead? If she has a status screen, does that mean she reincarnated in a game world? Do you remember if it was specifically an otome game?

Comment: I forgot to mention this before but the girl reincarnated as a kid. I don't remember when I last read this. I've been searching for the name for awhile now though. And the male lead wasn't mentioned so far from what I remember reading.

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240255 . No answers, but it includes some other details

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Carpe Diem](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/carpe-diem-sae-un)*.

> My god, is it easy to live! While I was doing a night shift at a PC room, I decided to play a daughter raising game out of pure boredom and nostalgia. But the ending she wound up with was... an Old merchant's concubine. When she got too annoyed and tried to find a different game to play next, a pop-up screen came up on her computer. [You are invited to our world! A place where you can get anything you want!] As soon as she clicked the yes button, she heard a butler's voice:"It's time to wake up, My Lady." Before she knew it, she had become the "daughter" of the game she just played! Ah, she probably would've chosen a better name if she'd known this. Rollypolly Perero. Why did a pack of cookies have to be in front of her when she typed in the name? Could a 24 year-old trapped in a **10 year-old's body** successfully manage to become an adult?

Most of the details from the question match, but there are differences. This is not a reincarnation story and the protagonist doesn't die (at least not onscreen), she's transferred into a game she was playing. Immediately after appearing in the game world, her stress levels skyrocket and she gets sick from that. The original body doesn't die. The MC retains all of her memories from before waking up in the game.

She and her father had a poor relationship. Before the story starts, she's essentially a living puppet with no motivation or personality, which makes sense in the context of a daughter raising game. After the MC takes over, due to her confusion, frustration, and just thinking of everyone else as NPCs, she refuses to call her father "father".

Her father is described as one of the top-four mages. After an incident, he gives her a set of magical earrings that changes her hair color from the initial silver to a dark blue, matching her father. As this is in a game, she still has status and schedule popup windows that no one else can see.

[image: Original appearance] [image: New appearance, with father and butler]

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is it, but maybe it’s “The Archmage’s Daughter”?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe how this matches the details in the question?

Answer (score -1):

It's *[Who Made Me a Princess](https://who-made-me-a-princess.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Made_Me_a_Princess)*. She knows her future because she read it in a novel. Her father hates her and kills her.

> The beautiful Athanasia was killed at the hands of her own biological father, Claude de Alger Obelia, the cold-blooded emperor! It’s just a silly bedtime story… until one woman wakes up to suddenly find she’s become that unfortunate princess! She needs a plan to survive her doomed fate, and time is running out. Will she go with Plan A, live as quietly as possible without being noticed by the infamous emperor? Plan B, collect enough money to escape the palace? Or will she be stuck with Plan C, sweet-talking her way into her father’s good graces?!

Edit: Not this one. It's different; I just checked

Comment: Next time, it might be better to do any necessary checking _before_ you post an answer.